# Using script_fields with Apache Beam's ElasticsearchIO.read().withQuery()

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I'm trying to read data from Elasticsearch using Apache Beam's `ElasticsearchIO.read().withQuery()`. I want to use a query that includes the `script_fields` parameter to compute a custom field as part of the query response. Here's an example of the query I'm trying to use:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "description": [
              "xyz"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "my_scripted_field": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "return "my scripted value";"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, when I run my Beam pipeline, I get an error message saying that the `script_fields` parameter is not supported. I believe this is because `ElasticsearchIO.read().withQuery()` [uses](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/27ada99648b07e6e32047df26193326d16e5cffc/sdks/java/io/elasticsearch/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchIO.java#L947) the Elasticsearch count API under the hood to estimate the size of the data to read, and the count API does not support the script_fields parameter.

Is there a way to use a query with the `script_fields` parameter in `ElasticsearchIO.read().withQuery()`? If not, what would be the best alternative to achieve this?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!